# two version issues error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I uploaded my project on apple store. I have one project more with some different from my first project. i copied my first project and changed project name, bundle name, bundle identifier and icon. when i run device or simulator, i can see my two different projects.
But when I upload my second project on iTunes i take following error.

Applications must be ready for upload on iTunes Connect before they can be validated or submitted from within Xcode.

What could be the issue ?

Is there anyone who has faced a problem like this before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to prepare for upload, i.e. configuring the application in iTunes Connect.

Access iTunes Connect -> Manage Your Applications -> Add New App

Comment: yes i forgot to press reedy to upload button. thank you